# Form AutoScaleMode=Font does not autoscale horizontally

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

I have a simple form with some labels, button, textboxes in my .NET5+ WinForms application. I notice auto scale problems when the text size is increased from **Make text bigger** setting in **Control Panel**.
For example, I increased text size to 110%. Here the differences between the same form but different text size setting:
[image: vertical comparison]
[image: horizontal comparison]

The controls are scaled vertically as expected. However, there is no auto scale horizontally. The X or Width properties are not changed. Because of this, some controls hides the other control behind when text size is greater than 100%. That doesn't occur when 100% text size is used.

I used both **.NET7** and **.NET8** **WinForms** application. DpiMode does not affect the result (I used SystemAware and Unaware). Form uses AutoScaleMode=Form. I also tested AutoScaleMode=Dpi.

When I was using .NET framework, it was not scaling. This behavior is better than scaling vertically only.

Is there any way to scale both vertically and horizontally? or at least, preventing to scale.

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel. In this case, its cells call auto-size when the content of child controls changes. Then the *bad news*: when you design a *form* (any kind) that is supposed to adapt to different Dpi resolutions / Font sizes, you need to make use of nested containers (Panels / TableLayoutPanels / FlowLayoutPanels / SplitContainers etc.), and design your app for that behavior explicitly, testing, possibly, different monitors with different scales, moving your windows between them - Use `PerMonitorV2` as the DPiAwareness mode